# Blender is reading full buffer from disk when rendering

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, error

So when I render scenes for some reason I keep getting this error and I have no idea how to fix it I use Cycles here are my settings for sampling I use 4096 and Optix Albedo and normal,
I also use Full global illumination for light paths it just sets all of the max bounces to 32 and I render at I'm rendering at 8k but still have problems at 4k.
I have a decent PC for blender I have an RTX 3060 and an i5 12400f with 20GBs of RAM and I use an SSD. but I am confused about why I keep getting this error.
Also if I were to Upgrade what type of PC upgrade would have the most impact other than a GPU upgrade?